# JQuery visible selector does not return the correct index

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, visible

i have this simple code http://jsfiddle.net/U4Fj9/
the index of the visible image is always 3 which is the last image while the visible image is the first one
i know it's very simple but can't see anything wrong with my code any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be
>   visible, since they still consume space in the layout. During
>   animations that hide an element, the element is considered to be
>   visible until the end of the animation. During animations to show an
>   element, the element is considered to be visible at the start at the
>   animation.

This method e.g. as replacment of your original one solves your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".show img").css("display","none");
   $(".show img:first").css("display","inline");
   var curImg = $(".show img").filter(":visible").index();
   $(".curindex").html(curImg );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".show img").css("display","none");
$(".show img:first").css("display","block");
var curImg=$('.show img:visible');
var i= $("img").index(curImg);
$(".curindex").html(i);
});
```